# Замена подстроки java регулярные выражения

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Приходит строка вида:

```
2016-11-28 07:28:34.5
```

Необходимо её обрезать и заменить, чтобы получилось:

```
28.11.2016 07:28
```

Проверяю, что соответствует 1 варианту, а как сделать замену,
без разбиения в массив не знаю

```
private String formatDate(String str) {
        if ((str == null) || (str.trim().equals(""))) {
            return "";
        } else {    
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.*"); 
            Matcher m = p.matcher(buf.readTab());
            if (m.matches()) {
                // здесь надо заменить
            } else {
                return str;
            }
        }   
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Предлагаю не использовать регулярные выражения а воспользоваться **SimpleDateFormat**:

```
String inputDate = "2016-11-28 07:28:34.5";
SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS");
SimpleDateFormat outputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
System.out.println(outputDateFormat.format(dateParser.parse(inputDate)));
```

> 28.11.2016 07:28